# vector within an object; genetic algorithm crossover

Tags: c++, vector, genetic-algorithm

I'm working to produce code that will enact a "crossover" operation for a genetic algorithm.  Put more plainly, I have two vectors 'a' and 'b' and each will be broken into two parts such that a gives 'a1' and 'a2' while 'b' gives 'b1' and 'b2'.  These parts are to be recombined so that a becomes 'b2' and then 'a1' while 'b' becomes 'a2' and then 'b1'.

Because of the library that I am using - [EvolvingObjects](http://eodev.sourceforge.net/eo/doc/html/index.html) - I need to pass 'a' and 'b' to an instance of a class which will perform the operation I described above.  I'm having trouble creating 'a1', 'a2', 'b1', and 'b2' in this class and I was hoping someone could tell me why.  My code is below.

```
class Quad : public std::vector<int>
{
    public:
    Quad() : std::vector<int>(4,0) {
    }

}; 

class QuadInit : public eoInit<Quad>
{
    public:

    void operator()( Quad& q ) {
        for( unsigned int i=0, n=4; i<n; ++i) {
            // rng is the random number generator of EO
            q[i] = rng.random(10);
        }
    }
};

class QuadVec : public eoVector<double,Quad>
{};


class eoQuadCross: public eoQuadOp<QuadVec>{
public:
    std::string className() const {return "eoQuadCross";}
    QuadVec a1;
    QuadVec a2;
    QuadVec b1;
    QuadVec b2;

    bool operator() (QuadVec& a, QuadVec& b){

    int cross_position_a = rng.random(a.size()-1);
    int cross_position_b = rng.random(b.size()-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < cross_position_a; i++){
        a1.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = cross_position_a; i < a.size(); i++){
        a2.push_back(a[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cross_position_b; i++){
        b1.push_back(b[i]);
    }
    for (int i = cross_position_b; i < b.size(); i++){
        b2.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    //Return bool
    return true;
}
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble* - compilation errors? Incorrect results? Aliens?

Comment: inheriting from an stl class is not advised.

Comment: a hunch: operator() might need `const` QuadVec references

Comment: @DCoder It builds fine but when I run it, all I get is "Run Failed."

Comment: Does your compiler not complain about using uninitialized variables? You're not setting `i` to 0 in two of those `for` loops. And do note that you're shadowing the `cross_position_*` member variables with local versions.

Comment: I'd be a bit dubious about this anyway. [`eoVector`](http://eodev.sourceforge.net/eo/doc/html/eo_vector_8h_source.html) inherits from `std::vector` too.

Comment: @DCoder  that was an error in my typing here.  Those i's are set to 0.  And I just tried deleting the constructor cross_positions and didn't do any good.

Comment: The last `for` loop uses `a.size()` instead of `b.size()`. Other than that, we don't know what produces your "Run failed" message, so this is shooting in the dark.

Comment: @DCoder Okay, thanks for your time.  I'll continue to fumble around with this and perhaps edit my question when I know more.